# smooch-bot-example not switching to another block

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, smooch

I am working on [smooch-bot-example](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example), I have set it up and uploaded to Heroku Git. I am getting bot replying successfully.

I am stuck in the scenario below. Here is my `script.js` file (see my `ADD_MOVIE` block)

```
'use strict';

const Script = require('smooch-bot').Script;


var YtsHelper = require('./libs/YtsHelper.js');
const FirebaseHelper = require('./libs/FirebaseHelper.js');
var firebaseHelperObj = new FirebaseHelper();

module.exports = new Script({

processing: {
    prompt: (bot) => bot.say('Beep boop...'),
    receive: () => 'processing'
},

start: {
    receive: (bot) => {
        return bot.say('Hi! I\'m Smooch Bot!')
            .then(() => 'showUserMenu');
    }
},

showUserMenu: {

        prompt: (bot) => bot.say("Here are the areas I can help you out. %[Add Movie](postback:ADD_MOVIE) %[Serve Food](postback:SERVE_FOOD)"),
        receive: () => 'finish'
},

ADD_MOVIE : {

    prompt: (bot) => bot.say('Enter movie name or keywords you want to search please.'),
    receive: (bot) => {

        bot.say("Search in progress...")
        .then(() => {
            // Call API Here
            return bot.say("Search Finished.")
            .then(() => 'TEST_ROUT') // Go to TEST_ROUT
        });

    }

},

TEST_ROUT: {
        prompt: (bot) => bot.say("Test rout called"),
        receive: () => 'showUserMenu'
},


finish: {
    receive: (bot, message) => {
        return bot.getProp('name')
            .then((name) => bot.say(`Sorry ${name}, my creator didn't ` +
                    'teach me how to do anything else!'))
            .then(() => 'showUserMenu');
    }
}

});
```

What I have done is calling an [yts Api](https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=fast) in my `ADD_MOVIE` block, upon success response I want to go to the block `TEST_ROUT` but I am getting this in Heroku log.

```
2016-08-24T09:48:15.304174+00:00 app[web.1]: Undefined state
undefined for user 1c91f4b02bf493fc6e8c606a,reverting to default state 'start'
```

I am redirected to the 'start' block. Here is my Facebook Messenger screenshot of conversation with bot

[image]

What I am doing wrong here? Please keep in mind I have to call the API and upon success I have to redirect the `TEST_ROUT` block.

**Update 1**

After applying solution, I am getting weird output. See image:

[image]

- TEST_ROUT is called before api results

here is my updated ADD_MOVIE block now

```
TEST_ROUT: {
        prompt: (bot) => bot.say("Test rout called"),
        receive: () => 'showUserMenu'
},

ADD_MOVIE : {

    prompt: (bot) => bot.say('Enter movie name or keywords you want to search please.'),
    receive: (bot, message) => {
        const movie_name_searched = message.text;
        return bot.say('Search in progress...')
            .then(() => {
               return YtsHelper.getMoviesList(movie_name_searched,function(movies_array){

                    if(movies_array[0] != "ERROR_FOUND" && movies_array[0] != "NO_MOVIE_FOUND"){

                        var movies_postbacks = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < movies_array.length ; i++){
                            movies_postbacks = movies_postbacks + " %["+movies_array[i]+"](postback:ADD_TO_FIREBASE)";
                        }

                        movies_postbacks = "Click any movie to add into firebase." + movies_postbacks;
                        bot.say(movies_postbacks);

                    }else{

                        if(movies_array[0] == "ERROR_FOUND"){
                            bot.say("ERROR Occured");
                        }else if(movies_array[0] == "NO_MOVIE_FOUND"){
                            bot.say("No movie found");   
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
            .then(() => "TEST_ROUT");
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement in the `receive` of `ADD_MOVIE`:

```
ADD_MOVIE : {
    prompt: (bot) => bot.say('Enter movie name or keywords you want to search please.'),
    receive: (bot) => {
        return bot.say("Search in progress...")
        .then(() => {
              return callMyApi();
        })
        .then(() => bot.say("Search Finished."))
        .then(() => 'TEST_ROUT');
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

The reason your messages are appearing out of order is because your call to `getMoviesList` uses callbacks, not [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

If you wrap your call in a Promise, and return that instead, it should work:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    YtsHelper.getMoviesList(movie_name_searched, function(movies_array) {
        if (movies_array[0] != 'ERROR_FOUND' && movies_array[0] != 'NO_MOVIE_FOUND') {
            var movies_postbacks = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < movies_array.length; i++) {
                movies_postbacks = movies_postbacks + ' %[' + movies_array[i] + '](postback:ADD_TO_FIREBASE)';
            }

            movies_postbacks = 'Click any movie to add into firebase.' + movies_postbacks;
            resolve(bot.say(movies_postbacks));
        } else {
            if (movies_array[0] == 'ERROR_FOUND') {
                resolve(bot.say('ERROR Occured'));
            } else if (movies_array[0] == 'NO_MOVIE_FOUND') {
                resolve(bot.say('No movie found'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes I know this. but I have to call the API in between the bot.say("Search in progress...") and bot.say("Search Finished."), How I will achieve this

Comment: also there is a return statement in inner then. please check again

Comment: Edited my answer. As long as your `callMyApi` function returns a promise, that should work

Comment: thanks for your help. see my update 1 in my question please.

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: Wow! this worked, thanks for your help. can you answer my this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103619/pass-param-to-postback-method-in-smooch-bot

Comment: is there any way to pass some params to postbacks with payload. please see my other question above